# FuelSDK to create a Contact through REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, community

I'm trying to accomplish creating a `Contact` in Marketing Cloud API. Im seeing that's the case in the API (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm)) but through the FuelSDK not sure how to.

How do I create a `contact` using the *FuelSDK*?